# descript synology folder from backup

Tags: encryption, synology

Last week my Synology diskstation had a crash of its volume. I was able to recover all files from a backup and my VMs by offloading the VDMK files, but one of the directories I only have in encrypted state. I was not able to decrypt is because Synology was readonly at the time, so I decided to upload all files to a USB drive and deal with it later.

Is it possible to decrypt the files? I have the key.

Comment: What encryption are we talking about? The one HyperBackup uses?

Comment: @Panki The encryption Synology uses to encrypt shares. I believe it is called "ECRYPTFS"?

Answer (score 0):

Recovering the encrypted files turned out to be very simple. Create a shared folder with the same name and passkey as the one in the old install, unmount it, copy all encrypted files from the backup to the new folder, mount the new share and presto, all files are back the way they were.